# Powershell Compression.Zipfile error

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-3.0, zip

I am receiving an error when running a script in Powershell. The script looks for two specific folders (one about 13GB and the other 1.5GB) in a directory and zips them appending a date/time string to the zip file name. It had been running without error for over a year. Until Christmas eve. The error is usually received on only one folder while the other is processed normally. It seems to be random which folder the error occurs on despite the script processes the folders in a specific order. The code has not changed since a it was put into production a year ago.

My error

> Exception calling "CreateFromDirectory" with "4" argument(s): "Data error (cyclic redundancy check)."

My code

```
{
    $fileNameAppend = (get-date -Format "_MM-dd-yyyy-hhmmss")+".zip"
    $sourceFolder = $sourcePath+$folder+"\"
    $zipFileName = $sourcePath+$folder+$fileNameAppend
    $destinationFileName = $destinationPath+$folder+$fileNameAppend

    If ( (Test-Path $sourceFolder) -eq $false )  
    { 
        Write-Error "Error reading Source. Folder location not found: $sourcefolder"
    }

    if ($error.Count -eq 0)
    {
        #Does not run on empty folder
        if( (Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder) -eq $null)
        {
            Write-Error "Error compressing folder. Source folder is empty: $sourceFolder"
        }
    }


    if ($error.Count -eq 0)    
    { 

        #Use .NET 4.5 to zip the folder to a file

        $startC = get-date -Format ("hh:mm:ss")
        Write-Output ((Get-Date -Format ("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))+"   Compressing Folder: $sourceFolder ...")
        $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
        $includebasedir = $true
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourceFolder,$zipFileName,$compressionLevel,$includebasedir)

        #Verify file was created
        if (![System.IO.File]::Exists($zipFileName))
        {
            Write-Error "Error compressing folder. File not found: $zipFileName"
        }    
        $end = Get-Date -Format ("hh:mm:ss")
        $diff = ($end|ts) - ($startC|ts)
        Write-Output ("Finished compressing in "+[string]$diff.Minutes+" minutes and "+[string]$diff.Seconds+" seconds.`r`n")
    }

    if ($error.Count -eq 0)
    {
        if (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists($destinationPath))
        {
            [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($destinationPath)
        }

        $startC = get-date -Format ("hh:mm:ss")
        Write-Output ((Get-Date -Format ("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))+"   Copying File: $zipFileName ...")
        [System.IO.File]::Copy($zipFileName, $destinationFileName, $True)

        $end = Get-Date -Format ("hh:mm:ss")
        $diff = ($end|ts) - ($startC|ts)
        Write-Output ("Finished copying in "+[string]$diff.Minutes+" minutes and "+[string]$diff.Seconds+" seconds.")

        Write-Output ((Get-Date -Format ("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))+"   Getting Hash ...")
        $sHash = GetHash $zipFileName
        $dHash = GetHash $destinationFileName

        if ($sHash -ne $dHash)
        {
            Write-Error ("Error copying file: $zipFileName Hash does not match. `r`n Source      Hash: "+[string]$sHash+" `r`n Destination Hash: "+[string]$sHash+" `r`n")
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Output ("Source      Hash: "+([string]$sHash))
            Write-Output ("Destination Hash: "+([string]$dHash)+"`r`n")
        }
    }

    if ($error.Count -eq 0)
    {
        Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder | `
           ForEach-Object {Write-Output ("Deleting: "+($_.FullName))  (Remove-Item $_.FullName)}

        Get-ChildItem $destinationPath | `
            Where-Object { $_.name -Like ($folder+"*") } | `
            Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $(get-date).('AddHours').Invoke(-2) } | `
            ForEach-Object {Write-Output ("Deleting: "+($_.FullName))  (Remove-Item $_.FullName)}
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that you are creating the zipfile inside the folder that is being zipped. Try moving it outside the `$sourceFolder` tree

Comment: @Eris The folder being zipped is G:\MSSQL_Backups\Alpha and the file Alpha_20130113123022 (Based on date time) is being zipped to G:\MSSQL_Backups.

Comment: did you tried another zip method?